# Hiding table row based on incremental php variable attached to the row

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

How can I hide a particular `<tr>` based on php variable associated with that `<tr>`(incremental variable `$i`) with jQuery when the table is being populated dynamically through Mysql. I have looked around but not getting any clue.

```
       <table id="example">
          <thead>
             <tr>
             <th>S.No.</th>
             <th>Item Number</th>
              <th>Question</th>
              <th>Option-A</th>
              <th>Option-B</th>
              <th>Option-C</th>
              <th>Option-D</th>
              <th style="text-align: center;">Correct Ans.</th>
              <th style="text-align: center;">Marks</th>
              <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
        <?php

        if ($query != '')  {
        $res        =   mysql_query($query) ;

            $i = 1;

        while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($res))

        {
        extract($row);

        ?>               
            <tr class="record">
            <td><?php echo $i ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item_no ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $level_id ; ?></td>
            <td><textarea disabled name="question" rows="4" cols="35"><?php echo $question ; ?></textarea></td>
            <td><?php echo $option_A ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $option_B ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $option_C ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $option_D ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $correct_ans ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $marks ; ?></td>
            <td> <a href="#" class="btnIcon glyphicon glyphicon-trash delbutton" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a></td>
     <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(function() {

                $(".delbutton").click(function() {
                    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                    if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {

                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "delete_entry.php", //URL to the delete php script
                            data: info,
                        success : function(response) {
                                   if(response=='deletion success'){
                                    $tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $tr.remove();  }); 

                                   }
                            }
                        });  
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                });
 </script>
             </tr>
        <?php $i++; } }    
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

And my ajax page,

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');  

session_start();

require("../config.php"); 
require("../Database.class.php"); 
require("../site.php"); 
$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);     
$fnc=new site_functions($db);

    $id     =   $_POST['id'];

    $deleted_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
  $deleted_by       =    $_SESSION['session_admin_id'] ;

  $nots = $db->idToField("tbl_ques","notes",$id);
   if ($nots == "")
   {
   $date_string = "last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }
   else {
   $date_string = $nots."last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }
     $fnc->update_is_not_deleted_for_Pearsonvue("tbl_ques",$id, "$deleted_date", $deleted_by);       
    $notes_data = array("notes"=>$date_string);

  if($db->query_update("tbl_ques", $notes_data, "id=$id")){
      http_response_code();        
      echo json_encode('deletion success');
    }else{
       http_response_code(204);       
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why need for jquery, you can use php- like <?php if(a == true){ echo '<html />' } ?php>}

Comment: Because I am receiving response from  AJAX on delete of any row. @AkhilAravind

Comment: If you have some recognisable identifier on the row then you can use $(row selector).css(display, 'none'). What do you get from the ajax response ?

Comment: @anand, give an `ID` to the `tr`, let it be like `table-row-$i`, where `$i`  is the incremental value,  on delete, pass the `$i` value to the ajax method. When you get `success` response from  back end, use the `ID` that you get on ajax method call and remove the `tr` with the `id` - Like `$('#'+id_to_remove).remove()`. This will remove the `tr` on ajax success. Hope you got my point. Let me know if you have issues.

Comment: I am executing a few mysql queries on Ajax page for deleting the row and receiving a success message. Now what I should do? @VanquishedWombat

Comment: I have added the code. Please take a look. @VanquishedWombat

Comment: I have added the code , please take a look . @AkhilAravind

Comment: i think `if(response=='deletion success'){
                                    $tr.fadeOut(1000); ` this is enough. did you try it ??

Comment: Take this bit ` $(function() {  $(".delbutton").click(function() {` outside of the php loop - you only want this once as `.delbutton` applies to *all* buttons with that class, not just the one you've just created.

Comment: What problem are you actually having with your code?  As above `$tr.remove()` would remove the row as you already have a reference to it within the `success:` callback.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I tried this `$tr.fadeOut(1000);` but what actually is happening is, my whole <tr> is breaking in two lines because I have applied `dt-responsive nowrap` initially when the page loads and after applying the code only that second line of `<tr>` is hiding but not the whole <tr>

Comment: then do one thing , in here ` <tr class="record">` add an id like ` <tr class="record" id="table_id_<?php echo $i; ?>"> ` . then on success callback, add `$('#table_id_'+del_id).remove()`

Comment: Done mate. No luck. Now even the second line is also not removing, Can something else be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already close - in fact it looks like your code should work on the first click at least. Anyway,

Change line

```
$tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $tr.remove();  });
```

to

```
$('#' + del_id).closest('tr').remove(); });
```

What this does is find the delete button element in the DOM, then look 'up' the DOM structure to the first TR element, and remove that from the DOM.

It is generally better to rely on simple variables within async callbacks because relying on objects, such as $this or in your case $tr can cause issues where the object pointed to by the $tr variable is not the one you expected.

EDIT: Added the working snippet below to illustrate the technique. If you still have a problem please create a [minimal verifiable version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a snippet from your code so that we can pinpoint the issue.

```js
$('.del').on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Second name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>Bloggs</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button id='A1' class='del'>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Bloggs</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button id='A2' class='del'>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Joanne</td>
      <td>Bloggs</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button id='A3' class='del'>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this but unfortunately its not  showing any effect. Problem remains same. Moreover using this line of code makes my table unresponsive and nowrap classes applied on table are removed . Can something else be done

Comment: Thank you for this. But actually I want to implement the same thing that you have shown above, but there are MySQL queries, php operations that I cant demonstrate in minimal version. I want the same to happen as you have shown above but the code you have used is not doing anything unfortunately.

Comment: have added `$('#table_id_'+del_id).remove();` in success function and `var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');` as variable and `<tr class="record" id="table_id_<?php echo $i; ?>">` in `<tr>`

Comment: That should all work - clearly there is some other bug. Check your code carefully and console.log($('#table_id_'+del_id).length) in the success func - if the value is zero then the selector is failing.

Comment: Yes its coming as `0`. I have implemented the same code as above. What more can we check now.

Comment: @anand - could you tell me what the bug was in the end ? I am guessing something simple maybe ?